# Creating expanded 1D array from 1D array elements without for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create an expanded 1D array from elements of 1D array using some numpy operation and without using a for loop. I would essentially read in the elements of 1D array and count up a few numbers(pre-determined value) from it and proceed to the next element to expand. See an example below.

1D array = `[1 9 20 56 78 120]`

expanded 1D array = `[1 2 3 9 10 11 20 21 22 56 57 58 78 79 80 120 121 122]`

is this possible? Thank you

I honestly don't have any idea how to do this without using a for loop

Comment: Why are you insisting on not using a for loop? It is possible. but why?

Comment: this array is going to be very large and I would like to avoid for loops and use vectorized calls if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
a = np.array([1, 9, 20, 56 ,78, 120])
n = 3
out = (np.arange(n) + a[:,None]).ravel()
```

Edit: explanation

`a[:, None]` is a shortcut for `a.reshape(a.size, 1)`. It creates a 2 dimension array. When I want to sum with `np.arange(n)`, this array is promoted to shape `(1, n)`. Then numpy broadcasts all `1` to the matching dimension.

`np.arange(n) + a[:,None]` has shape `(a.size, n)`. Then `ravel` is used to flatten it as a 1D array.

Comment: This looks great! Add some explanation, may be?

Comment: @arshovon It's essentially the same approach as in pho's answer, but with a clever trick for tiling and another clever trick for flattening.

Comment: This is also good. I actually ended up using this solution.

Comment: @Melonman could you please indicate the question as solved?

Answer (score 3):

use `linspace`:

```
a = np.array([1, 9, 20, 56 ,78, 120])
n = 3
np.linspace(a, a+n, n, endpoint = False, dtype = a.dtype, axis = 1).flatten()

array([  1,   2,   3,   9,  10,  11,  20,  21,  22,  56,  57,  58,  78,
    79,  80, 120, 121, 122])
```

Answer (score 1):

First, [tile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) the input array `N+1` times, where `N` is the number of subsequent elements you want to introduce.

```
input_arr = np.array([1, 9, 20, 56, 78, 120])

# In this case, you want N=2 subsequent numbers:
N = 2

tiled_arr = np.tile(input_arr, (N+1, 1))
# array([[  1,   9,  20,  56,  78, 120],
#        [  1,   9,  20,  56,  78, 120],
#        [  1,   9,  20,  56,  78, 120]])
```

Then, create an array from `np.arange`, which contains the integers to add to each row:

```
add_arr = np.arange(N+1)[:, None]
# array([[0],
#        [1],
#        [2]])
```

(the `[:, None]` converts a 1-d array to a column vector of shape `(N+1, 1)`)

Next, add this to your tiled array:

```
tiled_arr += add_arr
# array([[  1,   9,  20,  56,  78, 120],
#        [  2,  10,  21,  57,  79, 121],
#        [  3,  11,  22,  58,  80, 122]])
```

---

Note: You could skip the tiling step altogether and let numpy handle that automatically by [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the shapes:

```
tiled_arr = input_arr + add_arr
# array([[  1,   9,  20,  56,  78, 120],
#        [  2,  10,  21,  57,  79, 121],
#        [  3,  11,  22,  58,  80, 122]])
```

---

Finally, [flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) this array with `order='f'` to flatten this as a column-major array:

```
result = tiled_arr.flatten(order='f')
# array([  1,   2,   3,   9,  10,  11,  20,  21,  22,  56,  57,  58,  78,
#         79,  80, 120, 121, 122])
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using numpy broadcasting.

```
import numpy as np

n = 3
a = np.array([1, 9, 20, 56, 78, 120]).reshape((-1,1))
b = np.arange(0,3)

result = (a+b).flatten()
print(result)
```

Where `a` is like :

```
array([[  1],
       [  9],
       [ 20],
       [ 56],
       [ 78],
       [120]])
```

and `b` is like :

```
array([0, 1, 2])
```

and `a+b` will be like :

```
array([[  1,   2,   3],
       [  9,  10,  11],
       [ 20,  21,  22],
       [ 56,  57,  58],
       [ 78,  79,  80],
       [120, 121, 122]])
```

and the final result will be :

```
array([  1,   2,   3,   9,  10,  11,  20,  21,  22,  56,  57,  58,  78, 79,  80, 120, 121, 122])
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use list comprehension in Python if that is acceptable in your criteria.

```
ar = [1, 9, 20, 56, 78, 120]
n = 3
updated_ar = sum([[i for i in range(j, j + n)] for j in ar], [])
print(updated_ar)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11, 20, 21, 22, 56, 57, 58, 78, 79, 80, 120, 121, 122]
```

Explanation:

- Created a 2D list using list comprehension.
- Flatten the 2D list to 1D list using `sum` operator.

Comment: A list comprehension syntactic sugar for a loop.

Comment: I'm aware of that. However, during interviews, they often pose unconventional questions to assess one's grasp of Python concepts. Personally, I'm not in favor of incorporating such conditions in coding interviews.

Comment: A list comprehension is no different than a loop, so "without loops" also precludes list comprehensions in my book. If I asked someone I was interviewing to do something without loops and they came back with a list comprehension, I'd consider that a mark against that candidate. Given that this is tagged numpy, it's safe to assume that OP wants a numpy approach and "without loops" means "leveraging numpy's vectorization to eliminate python loops"

Comment: `[i+j for i in ar for j in range(n)]` You do not have to use `sum` again. Also this still falls under the umbrella of for-loops as mentioned by @pho

Comment: I understood that by "without for loop", OP means to avoid iterating within Python bytecode. Of course solving the problem requires iteration somewhere, but it can be pushed into Numpy's internals which are implemented in C.